# How to make a custom offline page using service worker in a create-react-app project?

Tags: reactjs, redux, service-worker, create-react-app, progressive-web-apps

I am new to service worker and PWA. Please tell me the default options provided by service workers in create-react-app. Does it cache the app shell by default? and is it possible to add a splash screen and custom offline page without ejecting?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

have a look at the [create-react-app](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/making-a-progressive-web-app/) description:

cache the app shell: yes

splash screen: yes, defined in the [default manifest.json](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/cra-template/template/public/manifest.json)

offline page: not by default, you have to program it yourself, or extend the app shell for offline case.

Comment: So for adding offline page is there any way to add it without ejecting?

Comment: No, I fear you have to eject the config files.